# Printing output formatting

Tags: python, printing, tuples, output

I have this function that takes a list and prints it out to an outfile:

```
 def writeToFile(files):

for path2 in files:
    fi= open(fileo, 'w')
    fi.truncate()
    fi.write('\n' + str(foundFiles2))
    fi.close()


foundFiles2 = [
'bb.TechnicalDefinition.UnitTests.vbproj'
'bb.Units.UnitTests.vbproj'
'bb.Utilities.UnitTests.vbproj'
'bb.Visualization.UnitTests.vbproj' ]
```

It prints to the file no problem however I want it to print a new line after every tuple in the list. However, when it write to the file it looks like this:

```
'bb.APDS.UnitTests.vbproj', 'bb.DatabaseAPI.UnitTests.vbproj', 'bb.DataManagement.UnitTests.vbproj',
```

I thought the

```
fi.write('\n' + str(foundFiles2))
```

would print out each tuple separately on a new line but it doesn't. Do I need a loop in here somewhere or is my syntax just plain wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should iterate over the list instead of printing it's `str` version.

```
>>> lis = [1,2,3]
>>> str(lis)      #str just returns a string representation of the string
'[1, 2, 3]'
>>> for x in lis : #use for loop to iterate over individual items of the list
...     print x
...     
1
2
3
```

your code:

```
for path2 in files:
    #"w" mode automatically truncates the file for you
    # Always use `with` statement for handling files, it automatically
    # closes the file.     
    with open(fileo,"w") as f:    
        for text in foundFiles2:  #iterate over each value in the list
            f.write(text+"\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

Open the file before the `for` loop and close the file after the for loop ( or use `with` like ashwini suggested because it automatically does that.)

The way you are going at it, it will only write the same `foundFiles2` list over and over again depending on how many indexes are in `files`.

If `foundFiles2` is the list you want to iterate over then you need to use it in the `for` statement:

```
for item in foundFiles2:
     fi.write(item+'\n')
```

this will go to the first item, and then write it, and then the second item and then write it etcetera.